# Slow serial encoding between Pi4 and Arduino for object tracking

Tags: pi-4, arduino

I have been working on a project that involved in Object tracking. I have been using the OpenCV and mobilenetSSD_v2 as my model with a google coral, the video itself has a bit of delay but it's still workable. However, when it tracked the target object and sent the command to move my motor through my Arduino UNO by using ser.encode(), the FPS dropped vigorously and caused the whole video to hang and delay. The motor controller I am using is Sabertooth 2x25 and I am using USB for the connection between Arduino and RPi. Is there a way for me to resolve this issue? Or must I connect my Pi to my motor driver with an extra level shifter instead? Thank you in advance.

Comment: sounds like your object tracking algorithm needs to be made much faster.  start by running the tracking on just a gui (just display a numeric position in motor coordinates to prove it can generate coordinates fast enough).  if that is fast enough then you have serial configuration issues or your messaging architecture needs work.

Comment: We can't guess where the delays/faults may be without seeing a lot more detail.